# Ansible gets stuck when I try to ssh with root user, gets denied with normal user

Tags: python, ssh, ansible

Here's my `inventory.ini` file:

```
[workers]
host_alias ansible_ssh_host=123.123.123.123
[workers:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=root
ansible_ssh_port=22
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=my_folder/id_rsa
ansible_ssh_pass=password
```

When I do `ansible all -i inventory.ini -m ping`, I get nothing, no error, the screen hangs. When I change user to somehing other than root, I get permission denied:

```
host_alias UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

However, if I do ssh -i file root@123.123.123.123 I get prompted for the private key password. If I do the same but with a non root user, I get:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

**UPDATE**: `ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1` gave me, as the last command before hanging forever:

```
_low_level_execute_command(): executing: /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1488620620.62-50272535751653 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1488620620.62-50272535751653="` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1488620620.62-50272535751653 `" ) && sleep 0'
```

Comment: Try with `ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1` and see what's going on...

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov did it, could you see the update?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `ansible_ssh_pass=password` is specific to password connections, cannot be used as password to private key. Taking it out solved the problem, but I have to enter it manually